# Split string into list contains alphabetical bullet list

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

My string contains 
`text = "a) Baghdad, Iraq b) United Arab Emirates (possibly)"`

I want to split this in list like
`["Baghdad, Iraq","United Arab Emirates (possibly)"]`

The code which i have used is not providing me the desired result

```
re.split('\\s*([a-zA-Z\\d][).]|•)\\s*(?=[A-Z])', text)
```

Please help me regarding this

Comment: Is it possible to have a string like `a) Baghdad, Iraq b) United Arab Emirates (possibly) c) Turkey if UAE is not in (b)`?

Comment: You are missing the `r` at the start of your regex pattern string.

Comment: [s for s in re.split('\\s*([a-zA-Z\\d][).]|•)\\s*(?=[A-Z])', text) if len(s) > 4]

Comment: @SarthakNegi that fails for `c) A`

Comment: @lxop yes it can also contains c d e so on......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create the wanted data for your example using a list comp and a second regex:

```
import re

text = "a) Baghdad, Iraq b) United Arab Emirates (possibly)"

# different 1.regex pattern, same result - refining with 2nd pattern
data = [x for x in re.split(r'((?:^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]\))|(?:\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]\)))\s*', 
                            text) if x and not re.match(r"\s*[a-zA-Z]\)",x)]
print(data)
```

Output:

```
['Baghdad, Iraq', 'United Arab Emirates (possibly)']
```

See https://regex101.com/r/wxEEQW/1

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `re.findall`, you can simply use `re.split`:

```
import re
text = "a) Baghdad, Iraq b) United Arab Emirates (possibly)"
countries = list(filter(None, map(str.rstrip, re.split('\w\)\s', text))))
```

Output:

```
['Baghdad, Iraq', 'United Arab Emirates (possibly)']
```